# Confusion about composite function and their ranges

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

let us take for example the two element set $\{a,b\}$ and the mappings $f:\{a,b\}\rightarrow a$ and $g:\{a,b\}\rightarrow b$. Then $g\circ f:\{a,b\}\rightarrow b$ and $f\circ g:\{a,b\}\rightarrow a$.

I am not entirely sure how this mapping works.

Functions $f$ and $g$ are defined on the set $\{a,b\}$. Does this mean that we use $\{a,b\}$ as the range for each mapping instead of the image of the first mapping?

Perhaps a bit more elaboration of my problem may help.

What I think is happening : $f\circ g(\{a,b\})=f(b)=a$. So at the step $f(b)$ do we use $\{a,b\}$ as the domain instead of the image of the function $g$ or are we mapping $b$ (the image of $g$) to $a$ ?

Comment: You are might confusing image and range. If you think more like that: $f: \{a,b\} \to \{a\}, x \mapsto a$ to split range and image (you have a messed up notation at that point), you might get a clearer view. Think for example of functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(\mathbb R)\neq \mathbb R$ if you are more used to that.

Comment: So if I change my notation to $f\circ g= f(b)$ What is the domain of $f(b)$? Thank you for the quick response btw.

Comment: The problem is, that $f(b)$ is not a function at all but a value (namely the evaluation of $f$ at $b$). On the other hand $f(g(\cdot))$ is a function with domain $g$ (supposing $range(g) \subseteq domain(f)$).

Comment: I think I understand what you meant by messing up my notation. I was considering the mappings to be individual mappings from each element of the domain instead of the whole domain itself. And $f$ is defined for $a$ so I can see how the mapping turns out. My main confusion came from not knowing how a mapping could be done when $g$ doesn't contain $a$. I hope that makes sense.